# Yii model: Dynamic table relations

Tags: relational-database, yii

**Table.linkedIndex** is related to **LinkedIndex.ID**. The value of the field **LinkedIndex.TableName** is either **Linked1** or **Linked2** and defines which of these tables is related to a row in **Table**.

Now i want to make a dynamical link with Yii models so that i can easily get from a **Table** row to the corresponding **Linked1** or **Linked2** row:

**Table.linkedID** = **[LinkedIndex.TableName].ID**

[image: DB diagram]

---

### Example

**Table** values:

[image]

**LinkedIndex** values:

[image]

Now I should get the row from **Linked2** where ID=2:

```
$model = Table::model()->findByPk(0);
$row = $model->linked;
```

---

### Model

In the model *Table*, I tried to make the relation to the table with the name of the value of **linkedIndex.TableName**:

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'linkedIndex' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'LinkedIndex', array('ID' => 'linkedIndex')),
        'linked' => array(
            self::HAS_ONE,
            'linkedIndex.TableName',
            array('ID' => 'linkedID'),
        )
    )
}
```

But then I get the error:

*include(linkedIndex.TableName.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory*

---

Is there any way to make a *dynamic* relation **Table.linkedID** -> **[LinkedIndex.TableName].ID** with Yii Models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the Yii docs here:

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#relations-detail

I'd suggest using self::HAS_ONE instead (unless there can be multiple rows in LinkedIndex with the same ID - although from the looks of above, I doubt that's the case).

You can link tables together that have different keys by following the schema:

foreign_key => primary_key

> In case you need to specify custom PK->FK association you can define it as array('fk'=>'pk'). For composite keys it will be array('fk_c1'=>'pk_с1','fk_c2'=>'pk_c2').

so in your case:

```
public function relations(){
    return array(
        'linkedIndex' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'LinkedIndex', array('ID' => 'linkedIndex')),
    );
}
```

where `LinkedIndex` is the class name for the LinkedIndex model (relative to your Table model - i.e. same folder.  You could change that, of course) and `array('ID' => 'linkedIndex')` specifies the relationship as `LinkedIndex.ID = Table.linkedIndex`.

**Edit**

Looking at your updated example, I think you're misunderstanding how the relations function works.  You're getting the error

> include(linkedIndex.TableName.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory

because you're trying to create another relation here:

```
'linked' => array(
    self::BELONGS_TO,
    'linkedIndex.TableName',
    array('ID' => 'linkedID'),
)
```

This part: `linkedIndex.TableName` refers to a new model class `linkedIndex.TableName`, so Yii attempts to load that class' file `linkedIndex.TableName.php` and throws an error since it doesn't exist.

I think what you're looking for is to be able to access the value `TableName` within the table `LinkedIndex`, correct?  If so, that's accessible from within the `Table` model via:

```
$this->linkedIndex->TableName
```

This is made possible by the relation we set up above.  `$this` refers to the `Table` model, `linkedIndex` refers to the `LinkedIndex` relation we made above, and `TableName` is an attribute of that `LinkedIndex` model.

**Edit 2**

Per your comments, it looks like you're trying to make a more complex relationship.  I'll be honest that this isn't really the way you should be using linking tables (ideally you should have a linking table between two tables, not a linking table that says which 3rd table to link to) but I'll try and answer your question as best as possible within Yii.

Ideally, this relationship should be made from within the `LinkedIndex` model, since that's where the relationship lies.

Since you're using the table name as the linking factor, you'll need to create a way to dynamically pass in the table you want to use after the record is found.

You can use the `LinkedIndex` model's afterFind function to create the secondary link after the model is created within Yii, and instantiate the new linked model there.

Something like this for your LinkedIndex model:

```
class LinkedIndex extends CActiveRecord{
    public $linked;

    public static function model($className = __CLASS__){
        return parent::model($className);
    }

    public function tableName(){
        return 'LinkedIndex';
    }

    public function afterFind(){
        $this->linked = new Linked($this->TableName);

        parent::afterFind();
    }

    //...etc.
}
```

The `afterFind` instantiates a new `Linked` model, and passes in the table name to use.  That allows us to do something like this from within the `Linked` model:

```
class Linked extends CActiveRecord{
    private $table_name;

    public function __construct($table_name){
        $this->table_name = $table_name;
    }

    public static function model($className = __CLASS__){
        return parent::model($className);
    }

    public function tableName(){
        return $this->table_name;
    }

    //...etc.
}
```

which is how we dynamically create a class with interchangeable table names.  Of course, this fails of the classes need to have separate operations done per-method, but you could check what the `table_name` is and act accordingly (that's pretty janky, but would work).

All of this would result in being to access a property of the `linked` table via (from within the `Table` model):

```
$this->linkedIndex->linked->foo;
```

Comment: The relation **Table** -> **LinkedIndex** is not the real problem, but the *dynamic* relation **Table** -> **"LinkedIndex.TableName"**!

Comment: I'm not sure I see the problem (maybe I'm misunderstanding the question).  Once they're linked, you can access `linkedIndex`'s properties from the `Table` model via: `$this->linkedIndex->tableName`

Comment: Just corrected my example with your inputs. The goal is to get the values from **Linked1** or **Linked2** like this:

*$this->linked->ANYVALUES* where **Table** is linked to the according table with **LinkedIndex.TableName**

Comment: Right, I need TableName to make the relation from **Table** to **Linked1** OR **Linked2** according to $this->linkedIndex->TableName. So with the call of *$this->linked*, I would get the row from **Linked1** OR **Linked2**. Something like this:
**Table.linkedID** -> **[LinkedIndex.TableName].ID**.

Answer (score 0):

Because the value of LinkedIndex.TableName and Table.linkedID is needed to get the values, I moved the *afterFind*, suggested by *M Sost*, directly into the *Table*-Class and changed its content accordingly. No more need for a virtual model.

```
class Table extends CActiveRecord {
    public $linked; // Needs to be public, to be accessible
    // ...etc.
    public function afterFind() {
        $model = new $this->linkedIndex->TableName;
        $this->linked = $model::model()->findByPk( $this->linkedID );
        parent::afterFind();
    }
    // ...
}
```

Now I get the row from **Linked2** where ID=2:

```
$model = Table::model()->findByPk(0);
$row = $model->linked;
```

Comment: Ultimately this will work as well, however since the linked table name is contained in `LinkedIndex`, it should really go within that model's class (as it's technically a property of that class).  This solution will work, though, for sure.  Also thanks for the reminder, `$linked` needs to be public to be accessible.